# Match the last number in a string

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to match the last number in a string, such as "34" in

> 3.1 General definitions 34

I am using Python-style regex, and I have tried:

```
(.*?)(\d)
```

so that later I can use \1 to refer "3.1 General definitions " and \2 to refer "34".

But \2 matches "4" instead of "34". So how shall I do?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: You said that you wanted to match the last number in the string.  Does the string always end with a number?  Would you want to match the number `88` in this string `'12 apples 88 oranges'`?

Comment: @Steven: my strings always ends with a number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're currently only matching a single digit. Try

```
(.*?)(\d+)
```

to match *at least* one digit. This should be all you need, as you've already made the first part of the match reluctant (non-greedy).

Depending on how you're performing the match, you *may* need an "end of string" anchor ($) at the end, to make sure it doesn't match the digits at the start of the string.

Comment: Yes, .*? means match any character zero or more times non-greedily (reluctantly).

Comment: @RobertB: Yup, just found that bit of the Python manual. Found another potential problem though :)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood his requirements, but he states that he wants to match the last number in a string.  He did not say that his string ends with a number (although his example certainly does).  If my reading of the question was correct, your answer is incorrect.  Otherwise, anchoring to end of string works.

Comment: @Steven: Good point. I sort of inferred that from the existing attempt at a regex. Will leave my answer as it is for the moment, in case my reading of the question is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Your original approach:

```
>>> re.match(r'(.*?)(\d)', '3.1 General definitions 34').groups()
('', '3')
```

Jon Skeet's answer (**edit:** I forgot to inculde Jon's suggestion to anchor to end of string, example is now corrected):

```
>>> re.match(r'(.*?)(\d+$)', '3.1 General definitions 34').groups()
('3.1 General definitions ', '34')
```

<strike>What I think is correct:</strike>  **new:** If the string doesn't *end with* a number, I would do it this way:

```
>>> re.match(r'(.*)(?<=\D)(\d+)', '3.1 General definitions 34 more text').groups()
('3.1 General definitions ', '34')
```

`.*` needs to be greedy to get the beginning of the string that you wanted, but we can't have it slurp up the first digit of `34` so we provide `(?<=\D)`, a lookbehind assertion, to stop it from happening

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
(.+?)(\d+$)
```

as it will giive you:

```
>>> r.groups()
(u'3.1 General definitions ', u'34')
```

You need to make it greedy at the begining.

Comment: This works provided that the string always ends with a number.

Comment: @Steven: The OP has said the string does indeed always end with a number.  This looks like the best answer to me.

Comment: @Alan: I ended up voting for Jon Skeet's answer as his was posted first.  They are both good answers.  Jon's is wordier, but makes up for it by providing more explanation.  berni's is more succinct.  Tie-breaker went to first posted.